# Filtering data usig date and keyword in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a table which contains data and say I am passing data from array1. On the top of table I have 3 panels and a button which are fromDate,toDate, keyword and a search button. I want the data to be filtered based on the 3 inputs once I click search button. My thought was to call a function using ng-click when I hit search button.

**HTML:**

<`button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="filter(toDate,fromDate,text)">Search</button>`

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.filter = function (toDate, fromDate, text) {

    var d1 = fromDate.format('MM-DD-YYYY');


    var d2 = toDate.format('MM-DD-YYYY');

    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[i].match(/text/g) != null && arr1[i].dateReported >= d1 && arr1[i].dateReported <= d2) {
            newarr[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }
};
```

But I am not able to know how to print and when to print new array. Is there a better way to do this. Thank you

Comment: I am not fully understand your question but as per mention, i would suggest to create model variable (or single variable) for each dynamic input or output (todate,fromdate, text and your array data ) which you going to bind those to your input types and your div (in case array data). also you don't need to pass ass parameter as you already having model variable define with your scope.
with this you dont need to worry about when your array going to bind back.
I hope this help you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd need to pass in the three parameters to your controller method.  Instead, you can expose these to the $scope and then reference the $scope variables inside the filter method.

The following is a quick example that should help you get on the right track. Please note, that this is using the controllerAs syntax within the controller.  More information on this can be found [Here](http://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/).  Also, I'm using the *indexOf* function instead of performing a regex search.

```
function fooController($log, model) {

   var self = this;
   self.fromDate = null;
   self.toDate = null;
   self.filterText = null;
   self.result = [];
   self.onFilter = filter;    

   // Populate our array from external source.
   var _myArray = model.populateArray();

   function filter() {      
     // May want to check and ensure that self.fromDate, self.toDate, and self.filterText 
     // are defined.  Exit gracefully or default them if not.

     // Splice array rather than initialize to '[]' so we don't lose the reference in the scope
     self.result.splice(0, self.result.length);  

     for(var i=0; i<_myArray.length; i++) {
       if (_myArray[i].indexOf(self.filterText) >= 0) && _myArray[i].dateReported >= self.fromDate && _myArray[i] <= self.toDate) {
         self.result.push(_myArray[i]);
       }
     }

     $log.info(result);
   };
};
```

Then your HTML would look like

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary pull-right' ng-click='vm.onFilter()'>Filter Data</button>
```